# React Redux: Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to integrate reducers in my app.js file, but I keep getting the following error:
React Redux: Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.
The code looks like below:

The reducers/booksReducers.js file

```
"use strict"

export function booksReducers(state={ books: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'POST_BOOK':
      // let books = state.books.concat(action.payload);
      // return {books};
      return { books: [...state.books, ...action.payload] }
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
  return state;
}
```

The reducers/index.js file

```
"use strict"

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

// HERE IMPORT REDUCERS TO BE COMBINED
import { booksReducers } from './booksReducers';

//HERE COMBINE THE REDUCERS
export default combineReducers({
  books: booksReducers
})
```

The main app.js file:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import  { reducers } from './reducers/index';

const store = createStore(reducers);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('current state is ', store.getState());
});

store.dispatch({
  type: 'POST_BOOK',
  payload: [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Book Title',
    description: 'Book Description'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Second Book Title',
    description: 'Second Book Description'
  },
]
});
```

I am not sure, where I am going wrong. Could anyone let me know what is wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main app.js file, replace

`import { reducers } from './reducers/index';`

with

`import reducers from './reducers/index';`

As in your redcuers/index.js, the `combineReducers` is exported as default. So, you don't need `{}`